# Installing sphinx on Dreamhost

Tags: mysql, sphinx, dreamhost

I'm following this tutorial: http://hughevans.net/2009/03/10/thinking-sphinx-dreamhost

I'm run into an issue when I run:

```
./configure --prefix=$HOME/local/ --exec-prefix=$HOME/local/
```

I get an error: "cannot find MySQL include files."

I've checked and cant find mysql_config, so I'm guessing the mysql-devel package isn't installed.

My next step is to install the mysql-devel package from source, but I'm thinking that I may be missing something.

Has anyone found a solution for this issue?

(I'm using a VPS)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by using a different user with root access.

With that user I installed sphinx with APT.

```
sudo apt-get install sphinxsearch
```

Answer (score 0):

> My next step is to install the mysql-devel package from source

Why from source?

Suggest just using a package manager to install the package.

Comment: Cause I don't have root access.

Comment: So you don't actully have a VPS then :( Your question is inaccurate

Comment: Should have been clearer.  I didn't have root access with the user I was logged in as.  I used a different user with root access and installed sphinxsearch with a simple `sudo apt-get install sphinxsearch`.  That solved all my problems the easy way!

Comment: You shouyld add that as a new answer, and then accept the answer. Marks the question as answered.